# Cygwin's Git command is removing the curly braces from a command. How do I prevent this?

Tags: git, bash, cygwin, curly-braces

I'm trying to run this command in cygwin:

```
$  git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all '@{u}..HEAD'
fatal: ambiguous argument '@u..HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

As you can see from that error, it thinks I'm passing in `@u..HEAD` instead of `@{u}..HEAD`.  Why are the curly braces being removed and how can I prevent this?

I am using bash:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

I think this may be the git command doing this, because if I just use echo, the curly braces stay:

```
$ echo '@{u}..HEAD'
@{u}..HEAD
```

Here's other info that may help:

```
$ git version
git version 1.7.9

$ type -a git
git is /c/cygwin/bin/git

$ git config -l
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
svn-remote.svn.url=https://myrepo/svn/results
svn-remote.svn.fetch=trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
svn-remote.svn.branches=branches/*:refs/remotes/*
svn-remote.svn.tags=tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*

$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{u}
fatal: ambiguous argument '@u': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
@u
```

Also if those `/c` paths are throwing you off, be aware that my .bashrc file has this line in it for my convenience: `mount c: /c`

**Work Around**: If I use this command instead `git log --oneline --graph --decorate -- '@{u}..HEAD'` it does not complain.  Notice the "--".  But by all accounts on IRC, I shouldn't have to do this.

Comment: What version of git are you using?

Comment: Also of interest: `type -a git`, and `git config -l`

Comment: Thanks for the help.  See my edits at the bottom

Comment: I have the same version as you but cannot reproduce the issue, even trying on a dummy branch with no upstream. Perhaps it is a bad interaction with `git-svn` config. What is the output of `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{u}`?

Comment: @GregBacon added the output to the bottom of the post

Answer (score 2):

Check the value of your `CYGWIN` environment variable.
Maybe in your case you can try using:

```
CYGWIN=noglob git log ... @{u}..HEAD
```

As in [this thread](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-09/msg00885.html):

> As I understand docs if I set `CYGWIN=noglob` then command line arguments passed to Cygwin app WITHOUT changes.

[That thread](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2011-11/msg00225.html) also asks for `CYGWIN=glob:nobrace` in order to limit the changes to only the curly brace, but I don't think it works yet in the current version of Cygwin.